# Dark Theme in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, themes

I can't seem to get this feature to activate. I have my config.inc.php file set with the following line:

```
$cfg['Console']['DarkTheme'] = true;
```

More info here:
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Console_DarkTheme

I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Is it possible your config.inc.php isn't being read for some reason? I suggest adding a line `die ("config.inc.php works correctly");` near the end of the file, then try loading phpMyAdmin again and see if the message appears.

Comment: Also, which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, it loaded it. I am running the latest version, which is 5.0.2. But I tried it on 4.9.1 and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 10):

Download a dark theme you like from [here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/themes/) and install it into the "themes" folder of your phpMyAdmin installation.

If you are using a local web server like XAMPP, you can simply open your XAMPP folder and search for "theme.json". Once you find one of the theme.json files, you will have to right-click on it and then click on "Open file location", then go to the parent directory and extract the downloaded theme there. The exact location should be: `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\themes`.

After you install your theme you will have to open your phpMyAdmin dashboard and, under "Appearance settings" panel, change the theme to the one you installed.

If you are using cPanel you should try this [link](http://hasif.info/2011/11/19/installing-phpmyadmin-themes-in-cpanel-server/) but I have only tried in XAMPP and it worked well.

Comment: Thank you for that link. It looks like it was just uploaded last month. However, it is very vibrant. The purpose of most Dark Themes is not minimize the stress on the eyes. Also, it still doesn't explain why the code in my question, which was in the PHPMyAdmin manual, doesn't do anything.

Comment: I had same like you but i couldn't do anything so i had to only use the link which i gave you and i suggest you to use eye saver app in your windows its might help you and resolve your problem.

Comment: thanks again, but i am on Windows 7 and cannot use apps.

Comment: @darkflux you can also use extensions which will make every websites dark mode but if you don't trust extensions as i don't trust so you can use OPERA GX this is name of browser which is having ability to convert websites to dark mode and i using it now for php my admin in Original theme and its looks awesome

Comment: thanks for the ideas Technosha, but if i wanted to do something like that, i would just use my Stylus settings in that Extension.

Answer (score 2):

There is possibly a misunderstanding of this configuration option. The `DarkTheme` configuration setting only enables the dark theme for the **console** at the bottom of the page. Hence `DarkTheme` being inside the `Console` array. Note the console is collapsed by default and you have to click the "Console"  tab to open it.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate (note only the console background is changed in dark mode):

### DarkTheme off

[image: phpMyAdmin console with light background]

### DarkTheme on:

[image]

Comment: .....well THAT is less than useful. although i suppose it does say "Console" in the setting text. so then is there no way to change the the interface itself to a dark theme?

Comment: @darkflux the only way would be to install a dark theme as Technosha mentioned in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64809011/2518200). Have you tried the "darkwolf" theme on [this page](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/themes/)? I saw the screenshot of it and it looks good. Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @darkflux Incidentally I've been trying to look for a dark theme myself (which is how I found your question) but I'm stuck on phpmyadmin version 4.9 and there aren't any good dark themes for that version so I've actually been working on creating one msyelf for 4.9. Perhaps I'll also make one compatible with 5.0 and contribute them to the site.

Comment: @CaveJohnson did you find (or make) one meanwhile? Finding myself in a similar situation, being stuck on 4.9 and darkwolf seemingly is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I just created [a pull request](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/themes/pull/73) on [phpmyadmin/themes](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/themes) for my new theme, [Blueberry](https://github.com/movahhedi/blueberry-pma-theme), A modern dark theme for phpMyAdmin.

You can get it from it's repository at [movahhedi/blueberry-pma-theme](https://github.com/movahhedi/blueberry-pma-theme),

Or download the zip file from [here](https://shmovahhedi.ir/work/repos/shahab-pma-theme/releases/shahab-pma-theme-v1.0.0.zip)

The installation is the same as [Cave Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518200/cave-johnson) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64809011/11041841)

Answer (score 0):

Here is ready to use [lightweight phpMyAdmin docker image](https://github.com/beeyev/phpmyadmin-docker-lightweight).
This project is automatically built on top of the official phpMyAdmin fpm-alpine image, it includes Caddy web server and two most popular dark themes:

[`Blueberry`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeKGA.png)
[`BooDark`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tNkb.png)

Answer (score -1):

/*# sourceMappingURL=theme.css.map */

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).